# Bitcoin full node на 20Gb

Tags: linux, bitcoin

Как запустить Bitcoin full node на VPS с 20Gb SSD (свободно 13)?

`bitcoin.conf`:

```
server=1
daemon=1
rpcuser=testUser
rpcpassword=testPass
prune=550
maxsigcachesize=4
blocksonly=1
maxmempool=100
dbcache=50
maxconnections=10
maxuploadtarget=20
```

С такими параметрами все свободное место забивается за 10 минут.
Устанавливал с этого баш скрипта https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheMerkle/EasyBitcoinNode/master/easyBitcoinNode.sh за исключением, в `./configure` добавил `-without-wallet` т.к. вылетала ошибка.

И еще вопрос, запуская сервер `bitcoind` так и должна происходить индексация всех транзакций с 2009 года (процесс займет несколько дней)?

P.S. Запускаю такой сервер впервые

Comment: купить vds побольше? хотя бы 250 гб

Comment: так он дороже будет)) не окупится)

Comment: @KoVadim такой серва стоит 5$/мес, а на 250гб ~60$. В любом случае дороже, а я знаю что можно запустить и на 20гб, но не на знаю как

Comment: вот это знание и стоит 55$/мес

Comment: Фул-нод не полезет и в триста. А prune - это не фул-нод.